# Allow custom icons for already made sty file

Tags: packages, fontawesome

I'm working on making a CV using a template called "A Customised CurVe CV" found on Overleaf, and so far I've been managing to incorporate my own style.
But right now I'm struggling with adding custom icons between the entry dates and the description. (see image below)

[image: This bookmark is set in the settings.sty file]
This `\faBookmark` icon is set in the settings.sty file line 120, how would I go about making it so I can change it on the fly on the document? I'm quite literally a noob when it comes to settings files in LaTeX, so any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Rafael.

[Not sure if it helps to post the code here...](https://justpaste.it/584b0)

Comment: You could try `\let\faBookmark\faYourFavoriteIconHere` in your main document.

Comment: That works well enough to change icons for a particular sub-file, but I can't use specific icons for each entry in those files, which is kinda what I'm looking for. I want to incorporate the schools + companies logos instead of the fontawesome icons.
Since, for example, for Education, I studied in 3 different schools, I can't just change the icon once in the main document or else all 3 schools will share the same icon.
Thanks for the help anyway, I'll use that as a last resort though :p

Comment: It's better to provide a complete example using `settings.sty`.

Comment: I can make an example if necessary, but I figure the Overleaf template should be enough to understand the framework..

Comment: In principle the Overleaf template should be sufficient, but we prefer the questions here to be self-contained, and not require any information from external links, for three reasons: 1. to make sure the question will remain useful even if the linked information/file changes or is removed and 2. because various people dislike following (semi-)random download links and 3. in any case with such a link it takes more effort from potential answerers to understand the question, get the code, and create a self-contained solution.

Comment: Admittedly Overleaf is a bit of a special case, because many people know and trust that service, and it might even make it easier to answer because you can just edit the code on the web interface instead of copying it to your own machine. But still reason 1 holds, and for overall consistency and explainability of site policy it is also better not to have exceptions to the common practise.